# Unexpected token (16:22) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, babel-loader

I get this error when I start my react project with npm start. Doesnt let me move forward at all.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-csv/src/components/Download.js 16:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no 
loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class CSVDownload extends React.Component {
|
>   static defaultProps = Object.assign(
|     commonDefaultProps,
|     defaultProps
 @ ./node_modules/react-csv/src/index.js 1:0-45 4:27-35
```

This is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: false,
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react'
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    ],
    env: {
        production: {
            only: ['app'],
            plugins: [
                'lodash',
                'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
            ],
        },
        test: {
            plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
                'dynamic-import-node',
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

This is my webpack config

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = options => ({
    mode: options.mode,
    entry: options.entry,
    output: {
        // Compile into js/build.js
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        ...options.output,
    }, // Merge with env dependent settings
    optimization: options.optimization,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: options.babelQuery,
                },
            },
            {
                // Preprocess our own .css files
                // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
                // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
                        options: {
                            // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
                            limit: 10 * 1024,
                            noquotes: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
                            limit: 10 * 1024,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                enabled: false,
                                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                                // enabled: true,
                                // progressive: true,
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false,
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 7,
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                                speed: 4,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 10000,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: options.plugins.concat([
        // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
        // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
        // drop any unreachable code.
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'development',
        }),
    ]),
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
        mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
    },
    devtool: options.devtool,
    target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
    performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

I tried installing stage-0 preset as the error was at static defaultProps but babel deprecated stage presets. Please advice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ok, If anyone is still struggling to fix this issue
This has solved it for me

```
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv/lib';
```

I think it is just the `src`  directory inside the module CSVLink which is creating the problem , Should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `options: options.babelQuery` or can you share what this is?

It appears you have `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` but assuming these custom options are overriding `babel.config.js`.

Either that or modify those options to include this plugin [as in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/):

```
use: {
  loader: "babel-loader",
  options: { plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] }
}
```

Comment: This is the boilerplate I used

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/internals/webpack